# How to deal with module name collisions in Python?

Tags: python

Say in my code, I need to use a 3rd-party package from Pypi which has a module `somemodule`. On the other hand, I have a user-defined module `somemodule` from which I need to import some functions. Is it possible to import from both modules in a single file?

Below is the sample code that illustrates the question. Is this even achievable?

```
import somemodule # a 3rd-party module

from userdefined.somemodule import somefunc# user defined module

somemodule.run()
somefunc()
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution you show?  I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: the solution you have posted *is* correct.  Python is so quick it's worth trying before posting...